# iTunes Store RSS feed by Artist Id?

Tags: ios, xml, rss, itunes

I'm having trouble configuring the URL to load an RSS feed of a particular artist's music into my app.
I'm using itunes XMLPerformace test Xcode project available on dev.apple.  I simply want to change:

```
   [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wpa/MRSS/newreleases/limit=300/rss.xml"];
```

into something that will load an artist's songs into the table view instead of the newreleases.

This resource seems to suggest additional feed generator options are availble, just not readily.
http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/blog/introduction---rss-feed-generator.html

Has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out apple only offers select RSS feeds.  Thus, I can not do it this way.

However, parsing a JSON request from the itunes store api appears to be the best solution anyways.

[Itunes Store Api](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html)

Parsing the request from there was a breeze.